# Neukirch's Abstract CFT. Help with a proof in abstract Kummer theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

First of all, unfortunately, writing all the notation and terminology that he uses would make this post very big. So, I'm really hoping from an answer that comes from someone that knows this book. Also because I believe that Neukirch is the only one who does this "abstract class field theory".

In Neukirch's ANT, in the chapter about Class Field Theory, there is the following Proposition:

[image]

I don't understand how these things he said in the red lines are true.

Can someone explain it to me? I'd really appreciate it.

From what I understand, he claims that $G_{L}$ is the intersection of open normal subgroups $G_{K_{i}}$ of $G_{K}$, which I don't get why is true and from this he tries to conclude the statement that $G_{L}$ is the intersection of  open normal subgroups $G_{K_{j}}$, where $G_{K}/G_{K_{j}}$ is actually cyclic for every $j$, using the argument which involves the phrase "interpreted as Galois groups of cyclic subextensions", which I also didn't understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Neukirch's argument is group-theoretic ("abstract"), even if he expresses it in the language of extensions and its Galois groups.

You have an abelian grup $G(L|K)$ (i.e., the abelian extension $L|K$) which is determined by its finite subgroups (finite subextensions) because it has finite exponente $n$.

Those subgroups are finite and abelian, so by the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups they are a direct sum of cyclic subgroups (cyclic subextensions).

The first underlined phrase ("On the other hand...") just puts this two pieces together.

Comment: Right. That first line was actually the most mysterious part, but I Just learned that it is a fact for general profinite groups that closed subgroups are intersections of open normal subgroups